# The axioms of metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

> Let $X\neq\emptyset$  and let $\rho:X\times X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$
>    with the following properties :
>
> a) for $\forall x,y\in X$, $\rho(x,y)\geq 0$
>
> b) for $\forall x,y\in X$, $\rho(x,y) = 0\iff x=y$.
>
> c)  for $\forall x,y,z\in X$, $\rho(x,y)\leq \rho(x,z) + \rho(y,z)$
>
> Show that $\rho$ is a metric on $X$.

I understand that I should show that we can use these three given  axioms to reach to the third one.

I substituted firstly $x=z$ and then $y=z$ in the triangle inequality, but really couldn't reach what I want.

If $x=z$, $\rho(x,y)\leq 0+\rho(y,x)$.

If $y=z$, $\rho(x,y)\leq 0+\rho(x,y)$.

Comment: You only need to prove that $\rho(x,y)=\rho(y,x)$, don't you?

Comment: Yes I know but how

Comment: I was trying to use the given axioms but I couldn't reach to  the wanted axiom.

Comment: @user416990: [**Please, look at how I've edited your question to use LaTeX / MathJax properly**](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/28c99ab0-90a7-4a6e-a104-03052663a68d/view-source).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a great idea to let $z=x$, and as you saw, you can conclude from statement (c) that for any $x,y\in X$,
$$\rho(x,y)\leq 0+\rho(y,x)$$
But since this is true for any $x$ and $y$, you can use the same $x$ and $y$ just in the other order!
$$\rho(y,x)\leq 0+\rho(x,y)$$

Now you have
$$\rho(x,y)\leq\rho(y,x)\qquad \rho(y,x)\leq \rho(x,y)$$
and the only way both of those things can be true is if $\rho(x,y)=\rho(y,x)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot it what I was trying to prove ...thanks